# SQL SUM a column when for certain values of another 2 columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to retrieve the sum of 2 columns, price and quantity.

My table has this columns:

- id
- doc_id
- customer_cif
- customer_id
- product_code
- quantity
- price
- origin

What I need is to get the sum of quantity and price for every customer_cif and product_code.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

This is my initial query (it gets repeated product codes and customer_cif)

```
SELECT id, doc_id, customer_cif, customer_id, product_code, origin,
SUM(quantity) as totQuantity, 
SUM(price) as totPrice
FROM sellings
WHERE created_at BETWEEN '2019-03-01' AND '2019-05-30'
AND (customer_cif = '01176854J' OR customer_cif = '01176862K')
GROUP BY customer_cif, product_code, doc_id
```

Without the doc_id I get this error:

> SQL Error [1055] [42000]: Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP
>   BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'sellout.sci.doc_id' which
>   is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is
>   incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: `SELECT customer_cif, product_code, SUM(quantity), SUM(price)
FROM my_table
GROUP BY customer_cif, product_code`

Comment: Well, literally interpreting your request it would be `select customer_cif, product_code, quantity + price from table` but that makes no sense - perhaps if you can understand how I interpreted your question it will help you refine it to a question that reflects what you actually want

Comment: I did try to do it, but  I get repeated  product_code, I will put my query in an edit

Answer (score 0):

**try this:**

```
select
customer_cif ,product_code,
 sum(coalesce(quantity, 0)+coalesce(price, 0) )
from your_Table
group by customer_cif ,product_code;
```